oci: How to use REST sdk call to create instance with GPU shape setting gpus
I can do the below command in CLI and
oci compute instance launch -c ocid1.compartment.AK00684129.broom15.xri7sc0a2upguqn5cn8ajnwi9664jtbc9cd7vib6x974ghk1dfg757hxpme5 --availability-domain AD-1 --shape VM.C3.GPU.L40S.Flex --shape-config '{"gpus": 1,"ocpus":4,"memoryInGBs":48}' --source-details '{"bootVolumeSizeInGBs": 100, "image_id": "ocid1.image.AK00684129.broom15.5sprgqr09pc5dtjb4p959h12clg5ebeq1tlh37jrpfshzvtdy054us8c0623", "source_type": "image"}' --subnet-id ocid1.subnet.AK00684129.broom15.c67zxe3fwglsldmv3xfc9s1jqc4zkbmrv5bfmd8nwqvdezyrfrq25ev5fbg4 --assign-public-ip True --ssh-authorized-keys-file /nfs/shared_storage/ossetest/usr/src/tests/pca_3x/CE/oci_keys/id_ecdsa.pub --display-name gpu-inst-test

BUt the sdk does not contain the gpus attribute in LaunchInstanceShapeConfigDetails
https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/tools/python/2.135.2/api/core/models/oci.core.models.LaunchInstanceShapeConfigDetails.html
So i am unsure of how to set it via REST. Can you advise

Are you able to create an instance with the no.of gpus mentioned in the CLI command? It looks like CLI is probably dropping the gpu attribute.
